# Cannot iterate through results from DSS with ForEach mediator possibly due to namespace

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I am having a great deal of difficulty with XPath finding any data in results returned from a DSS service.

This is a sample of the data returned:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Entries xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
<Entry>
    <FirstName>Sandra</FirstName>
    <LastName>Carr</LastName>
    <FlightDate>2016-07-23T18:24:12.000-04:00</FlightDate>
    <Duration>2.8</Duration>
    <FlightEndTime>2016-07-23T21:24:12.000-04:00</FlightEndTime>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <FirstName>Lawrence</FirstName>
    <LastName>Day</LastName>
    <FlightDate>2016-07-23T18:02:21.000-04:00</FlightDate>
    <Duration>2.8</Duration>
    <FlightEndTime>2016-07-23T21:02:21.000-04:00</FlightEndTime>
</Entry>
```

I have a simple synapse API sequence which is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/pilots" name="GetPilots" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET">
    <inSequence>
        <call>
            <endpoint key="GetPilotsRestEndpoint"/>
        </call>
        <foreach description="" expression="/Entries/Entry" id="field">
            <sequence>
                <log description="" level="custom">
                    <property name="tag" value="Entry"/>
                </log>
            </sequence>
        </foreach>
        <log level="full"/>
        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

I am not getting any results.  I am wondering if it is because of the namespace in the "Entries" tag.

In any case, would someone please help me with how I can iterate through the results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here. 
1. Your payload has a namespace `http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice` and you need to add that to your XPath
2. The response from the backend looks like below.

```
<Entries xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
<Entry>
    <FirstName>Sandra</FirstName>
    <LastName>Carr</LastName>
    <FlightDate>2016-07-23T18:24:12.000-04:00</FlightDate>
    <Duration>2.8</Duration>
    <FlightEndTime>2016-07-23T21:24:12.000-04:00</FlightEndTime>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <FirstName>Lawrence</FirstName>
    <LastName>Day</LastName>
    <FlightDate>2016-07-23T18:02:21.000-04:00</FlightDate>
    <Duration>2.8</Duration>
    <FlightEndTime>2016-07-23T21:02:21.000-04:00</FlightEndTime>
</Entry>
```

However, when it reaches ESB, it gets wrapped with SOAP envelope and will look like below. You can verify this by enabling wire logs or adding `<log level="full"/>` right after `call` mediator.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Entries xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <Entry>
                <FirstName>Sandra</FirstName>
                <LastName>Carr</LastName>
                <FlightDate>2016-07-23T18:24:12.000-04:00</FlightDate>
                <Duration>2.8</Duration>
                <FlightEndTime>2016-07-23T21:24:12.000-04:00</FlightEndTime>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <FirstName>Lawrence</FirstName>
                <LastName>Day</LastName>
                <FlightDate>2016-07-23T18:02:21.000-04:00</FlightDate>
                <Duration>2.8</Duration>
                <FlightEndTime>2016-07-23T21:02:21.000-04:00</FlightEndTime>
            </Entry>
        </Entries>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Therefore, your XPath `/Entries/Entry` would not work since the starting element is not Entries but Envelope.

Please use the following configuration (with `//`) instead where `Entries` element would be matched wherever it appears in the payload.

```
<foreach xmlns:ns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" id="field" expression="//ns:Entries/ns:Entry">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it must be a namespace issue. Try this.

```
<foreach description="" expression="//ns:Entries/ns:Entry" id="field"
xmlns:ns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
```

Comment: Thank you Bhathiya,
I am still not getting the log mediator to fire inside of the foreach mediator. My expected behavior is that I would have the word "Entry" written each time there is an Entry within Entries.  Given the above, is this what you would expect also?  Is there another problem I am not seeing?

Comment: Try xpath like this. `"//ns:Entries/ns:Entry"`